# Help with formatting a SharePointWebControls:TextField

Tags: branding

I am working on a page layout, and this is what I have ...

```
<!-- Title -->
<SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="Title" runat="server" ID="Title" CssClass="emedia-spwc-global"></SharePointWebControls:TextField>
```

The field displays and edits no problem. But it is just a text field. How do I tell the control I want it to be displayed with in H1 tags with out wrapping the entire control in H1 tags.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an EditModePanel to display two different controls when editing and displaying:

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat=server PageDisplayMode="Edit">
    <SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="Title" CssClass="emedia-spwc-global" runat="server" />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>

<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat=server PageDisplayMode="Display">
    <h1>
        <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Title" CssClass="emedia-spwc-global" runat="server" />
    </h1>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Comment: Wow again Whitelaw!

That was perfect! Thanks ... again